# How to iterate over a list to create a map before returning a widget? Flutter - Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, iterable

I want to create a widget that will generate multiple CheckboxListTiles based on a loop over a map. The key of each entry is a ProfessionalService and its value is a boolean value (which represent if the box is checked or not). ProfessionalIdentityModel possess a list of ProfessinalService. I want to iterate over the map in order to create mulitple CheckBoxTiles. 
My code looks like :

```
Widget serviceTile(ProfessionalIdentityModel professionalIdentityModel) {
Map boolServiceMap = {
  for (var service
      in professionalIdentityModel.professionalServices.services)
    service: false
};

return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    boolServiceMap.forEach((service, boolean) {
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text(service.name),
        value: false,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            service[boolean] = value;
          });
        },
      );
    })
  ],
);
```

}
I want to create my map based on my list of ProfessionalService. It must be done before returning my widgets. The problem is only 1 CheckBoxTiles is populated because my map contains only 1 element. Could you find a solution where my map contains all the element?

Could you help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want, could you elaborate further? What do you mean by `This is the case but for only 1 element`? And what about `The list iterates only once and then return the column.` is this what you want? Seems useless.

Comment: @mFeinstein Sorry I edited my post. Hope it's clarified.

Comment: Since you are sure that `professionalIdentityModel.professionalServices.services` have more than 1 item, I don't know why it's only iterating once.

Comment: @mFeinstein Thanks for trying to help me. When I use this     `return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (var service
            in professionalIdentityModel.professionalServices.services)
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(service.name),
            value: false,
            onChanged: (bool newValue) {
              setState(() {});
            },
          )
      ],
    );` the checkboxlisttyles are populated with all the elements.

Comment: I thought about this, but since the first loop wasn't iterating I didn't see why it would change.

Comment: Ohhhh ok I know why the first one wasn't iterating, I will post it as an answer explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Map` needs to have **unique** keys, if all your `services` have the same object, all the keys will be equal and not unique.

Each time you want to add an entry, the new key will be the same as the last key. When Maps receive a key equals to another one they already have, they just override the value of that key and that's why your `Map` only has one item.

What you are doing is something like this:

```dart
Map myMap = { 'myInt': 1 };

myMap['myInt'] = 2;
myMap['myInt'] = 3;
myMap['myInt'] = 4;
```

At the end `myMap` will have just one entry: `'myInt': 4`.

The only way your `Map` could work was if all your services were different objects.

It was hard to understand this at first because you didn't post the type of your services and how they are being built, so I assumed they were all different, as usually we don't create the same Service multiple times, but different Services that do different things (Single-Responsibility Principle).

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure to understand. The key is a type of ProfessionalService which has a name and a price as an attribute. There are indeed several ProfessionalService but they don't have the same attributes which make them unique no?. TIf my Map is like {'key1' = 3, 'key2' = 4}, the keys are of type String (and different) hence the map is still valid. I missed something and hope you have patience to explain me. Thanks

Comment: You only posted parts of your code and I need to guess the rest, somehow all the services are the same, the `Map` is seeing the same `key` each time, so it's replacing the same value all the time. Check the values inside `services` and be sure they are indeed unique, like `services[0] != services[1]` as Map uses `==` and `hashcode` to compare keys, so if you override these `Map` can think the values are equal even when they are not.

Comment: I've tested and you're right. services[i] is always equal to services[i+1]. So it means that these variables are pointing to the same Object aren't they?

Comment: It looks like they are, you should take a look at this.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I've just extend ProfessionalService with Equatable and it worked.

Comment: You can also take a look at `built_value`.